# OpenCV haartraining - Out of memory

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

Possuo 30 imagens positivas e 60 imagens negativas. Quando eu tentei executar o haartraining com 4GB de memória e processador Quadcore, eu recebo essa mensagem de erro:

```
OpenCV ERROR: Insufficient memory (Out of memory)
  in function cvAlloc, cxalloc.cpp(111)
Terminating the application...
  called from cvUnregisterType, cxpersistence.cpp(4933)
```

O comando que executei foi:

```
./opencv-haartraining -vec vector/myvector.vec -bg negatives.txt -npos 24 -nneg 55 -mem 2048 -mode ALL -w 86 -h 150
```

O computador nos momentos dos testes estava utilizando menos de 800 MB de memória, mas durante a execução do comando acima, a memória utilizada passa para mais de 3GB e mais 1 GB aproximadamente de swap, tudo isto em menos de 5 minutos de execução do programa.

Alguma sugestão do que pode ser feito para resolver este problema?

Comment: Pode ter um memory leak no seu código. Ou seu código precisa alocar tudo isso de memória mesmo? Tem como mostrar mais do código?

Comment: Que tamanho é o seu myvector.vec?
Eu já rodei o haartraining num computador de 4GB de RAM para mais de 3k imagens usando esses parâmetros: "opencv-haartraining -data Haarcascade -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.dat -nstages 18 -minhitrate 0.999 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -npos 2032 -nneg 3000 -w 64 -h 128 -nonsym -mem 768 -mode ALL"

Comment: @LucasNunes, a biblioteca que estou utilizando para gerar os classificadores está disponível em: https://github.com/mrnugget/opencv-haar-classifier-training. Pode ser que dentro dela tenha algum memory leak mesmo.

Comment: @vs06, o arquivo .vec está vazio.

Comment: O arquivo .vec é o arquivo que contém todas as imagens positivas simétricas. Você chegou a gerar ele a partir do aplicativo "opencv-createsamples"?

Comment: Obrigado @vs06, diversos motivos geraram a alocação de memória excedente, o primeiro deles que não reparei nos erros do createsamples, e o segundo motivo é que o tamanho e a quantidade das imagens positivas e negativas estavam sendo alocadas na memória. Agora está processando normalmente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme os comentários na pergunta, eu estava passando muitas imagens relativamente grandes (-w 86 -h 150) como parâmetro. 
Como a engine do OpenCV aloca as imagens e os exemplos em memória antes de gravar no disco, ocorria o estouro devido ao tamanho e quantidade.

Para solucionar o problema, reduzi o tamanho das imagens de exemplo não estourou mais a memória da minha máquina.

Comment: Olá Elexsandro. Que bom que seu problema foi resolvido. Mas dá pra melhorar um pouquinho essa resposta para que ela também sirva pra ajudar outras pessoas no futuro? O problema é bem claro (excesso de utilização de memória), mas a solução não está nada clara. Se você elaborar melhor a resposta ganha meus votos positivos nela e na pergunta. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira, obrigado pelo feedback, aprimorei a resposta conforme solicitado :)

Comment: Valeu! Como prometido, votei nas suas postagens. :)

Answer (score 0):

Quando o `haarcascade` é utilizado devemos especificar os mesmos parâmetros utilizados no `createsamples`, como `-w` e `-h`.

Comment: Oi Fabricio. [O comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41162/opencv-haartraining-out-of-memory#comment126762_41697) que fiz para o autor da pergunta também é válido aqui pra você. Seria importante você melhorar a sua resposta, porque do jeito que ela está eu creio que ela seja de pouca ajuda para outro usuário (principalmente se ele for menos experiente com o uso da biblioteca em questão).

Comment: Ok. Obrigado pela dica. As próximas serão melhores. ;)

Comment: Ola você esta executando via DOS ou instalou o python no Windows ? Estou fazendo o mesmo procedimento. No meu caso nao da erro nenhum mas o processamento para e da erro e nao posso diminuir mais ainda as imagnes positivas do que ja estão entende tenho 154 positivas de 100 x 55 e 600 negativas